# How to vertically center content in a cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How can I vertically center the content in the cells of the left table (marked 1) so that it looks like the cells of the right table (marked 2):

[image]

My code thus far:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \caption{Local Area Network vs Wide Area Network.}
    \label{tab:lanvswan}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}
        |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
        |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
        }
        \thead{Características}     & \thead{LAN}                           & \thead{WAN}                                                       \\  \hline
        Extensión Geográfica        & Pequeña                               & Extensa                                                           \\  \hline
        Dispositivos                & Host, Switches (L2 y L3) y Routers    & Especializados de ATM y Frame Relay, Switches (L3) y Routers      \\  \hline
        Tecnologías                 & Ethernet                              & MPLS, ATM, Frame Relay y X.25
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: use `m{...}` option from `array` package instead of `p{...}`.

Comment: when use m{...}  it gives me error :(

Comment: We need a complete example which generates the error - whichever error it is, which you haven't said, but we need to know that too.

Comment: Please provide complete examples when you ask questions. Please also consider accepting answers to some of your existing questions. In at least some cases, you've said an answer solved the problem, but you haven't accepted it even when people have put a lot of work into constructing examples from scratch which you didn't provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
%    \setcellgapes{5pt}
%    \makegapedcells
    \caption{Local Area Network vs Wide Area Network.}
    \label{tab:lanvswan}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm}% instead of "p" is "m"
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.5cm}
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.5cm}
    }
    \thead{Características}     & \thead{LAN}                           & \thead{WAN}                                                       \\  \hline
    Extensión Geográfica        & Pequeña                               & Extensa                                                           \\  \hline
    Dispositivos                & Host, Switches (L2 y L3) y Routers    & Especializados de ATM y Frame Relay, Switches (L3) y Routers      \\  \hline
    Tecnologías                 & Ethernet                              & MPLS, ATM, Frame Relay y X.25
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

`\makegapedcells` is not compatible with `m{...}` column type, so instead gaped cells I suggest to increase `\arraystretch`, for example as it used in above MWE.

[image]